# Mongoose How to get chid data using parent to parent using model in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i am working on mongoose database

[image: demo image in mysql table]

i have tried with several way but didn't get the success

Here is the sample query in SQL which i have to convert in mongoose query with model to improve the performance result.

**SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE teacher_id in (SELECT id from users where parent_id = 1)**

Please check the below screenshot for response. this is the response i need in mongo db using model query

[image: Response image]